# django app is working while not included in settings.py

Tags: django

I am reading the tutorials for django on their site.

In the first tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/ they are creating an app called *polls* and a view inside, and when running the server the view is displayed.

However, in the second tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/ it is mentioned that the app should be added in the installed apps section of the settings.py

> To include the app in our project, we need to add a reference to its
>   configuration class in the INSTALLED_APPS setting. The PollsConfig
>   class is in the polls/apps.py file, so its dotted path is
>   'polls.apps.PollsConfig'. Edit the mysite/settings.py file and add
>   that dotted path to the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

I am not sure how it worked in the first tutorial without including the app. Isn't it mandatory to include the app? or is it mandatory only in specific use cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to show some static view of an app, defining the url is enough(which may be done in the main urls itself). However, if your app has some models and you need to include it in migrate command (and to get its tables created), you need to include it in the installed_apps.

Comment: Also for admin autodiscovery and template tag registration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's mandatory to include each app you want to use in your project to INSTALLED_APPS. It helps django build paths to it's (app's) models, views, middlewares etc. It depends not only to apps written by yourself but also for third-party apps which extends django's functionality, for example django rest framework, modeltranslation and so on.

Comment: Thank you, however in this case how come it works in the first tutorial without including the app?

Comment: Well, perhaps I described this not quite correctly. You can use some parts of your app such as views, utils and so on but django will not make model's migrations and some other stuff with unplagged app.